spresenseの消費電流を知りたい
SPRESENSEを連続動作させている場合の標準的な消費電力をしりたい。もしくは計算方法があればそれを教えてください

こちらの記事のコメントで紹介したのと類似ですかね。SPRESENSEの消費電力を知りたい

ずっと昔測定してみた値があります。今はもっと改善しているかもしれません。
テスターで測ったいい加減なものですので、あくまで参考レベルにしてください。
抜粋すると次の通りです。
SPRESENSEメインボード　（USB端子給電の場合）
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-12-01



周波数
消費電流




156MHz
8.8 mA


32MHz
4.4 mA


8MHz
4.0 mA



SPRESENSEメインボード　（バッテリ端子給電の場合）
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-12-08



周波数
消費電流




156MHz
9.0 mA


32MHz
3.7 mA


8MHz
3.1 mA



SPRESENSEメインボード電力比較



周波数
USB給電(5.0V)
バッテリ給電(3.7V)




156MHz
44 mW
33 mW


32MHz
23 mW
13 mW


8MHz
20 mW
11 mW



その他にもカメラを使った場合の消費電力なども測っていました。ご参考になれば。
https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2020-02-21

既に完成しているブツの「標準的な電力値」なら、まあ普通は電圧電流計＋ロガーを仕掛けて測定しながら、いろいろな動作を試すくらいで十分です。
オイラたちが何かの製品の電源回路を設計する際にはもっといろいろなことを考えます。電源投入時の突入電流値だの電源断時の瞬間最大電圧値だのは基本で、※※時とか△△時とか〇〇時とか。この辺で考慮が抜けると後で後悔します（馬から落馬）標準的な消費電力値だけで設計することはありません。
まあすべてをパーフェクトに設計するのではなくて必ずコストも考えますけれども。
